# Angular5 WebApi token authorization not working

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, authorization, token, angular5

I'm trying to implement token authorization for Angular5 client and WebApi server application. I have managed to create WebApi part of the project in question and when I try to get the token via "POSTMAN" I get a good response:
[Postman request and server answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obgJF.jpg)

I'm trying to achieve the same with Angular5. This is my call from angular:

```
login(user: string, pass: string) {
    let params = new HttpParams()
        .append('grant_type', 'password')
        .append('username', user)
        .append('password', pass);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 return this._http.post<boolean>('auth', params, { headers: headers });
}
```

When I run this, I'm keep getting "bad request" from server.[Chrome response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gm1Y.jpg)

If anyone has any idea, I would appreciate help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/48140734/1160794

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks David for your help. I tried your solution but it didn't help until I changed my WebAPI CORS settings. The issue was with Pre-flight CORS request. I followed instructions in [this article](https://hgminerva.wordpress.com/2016/05/26/having-problem-with-pre-flight-cors-request-with-your-angular-2-app-and-web-api-2/) and that solved my issue.

In short:

1. I cleared all settings regarding CORS on my WebAPI and installed `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` package.
2. Then I modified the `ConfigureAuth` method in the `App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs` file with the following code:

   `public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions); 
   }`

That solved the issue, even with my code in Angular from the question. It now works fine.