# Angular Error 403: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: angularjs, angular, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have the following post request by which I am trying to upload a `PDF` FIle on `Alfresco Community Version On-Premise` Server:

```
      var urlPost = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload?alf_ticket=' + ticket;
      let header = new HttpHeaders();
      header = header.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("user:passwoed"));
      var formData = {
        filedata: file,
        filename: fileName,
        siteid: 'uploadsite',
        containerid: 'documentLibrary',
        uploadDirectory: '/',
        description: 'Test description',
        contenttype: 'cm:content',
        thumbnails: 'doclib',
        overwrite: 'false',
      };
      this.http.post(urlPost, formData, { headers: header }).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      }, err => {
        console.log("User authentication failed!");
      });
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
 Error 403: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.
```

It works when I hit request with `postman`.After some research, I have found that I need to change my back-end to not to require authentication for the OPTIONS method, but I am not sure how to do that too.

I am new here and any help will be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with my Angular 5 application. Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813793/angular5-webapi-token-authorization-not-working) for back-end settings. There you will find how I resolved issue with preflight requests.

If you need more help please let me know.